# ASPBoilerplate BackgroundJobs database pooling

Tags: c#, aspnetboilerplate, quartz, abp

I am using ABP framework to develop a web application. By default, the default background job manager pools the database every five seconds to find possible existing defined jobs. According to [ABP documents](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Background-Jobs-And-Workers)  and its [implementation](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/blob/dev/src/Abp/BackgroundJobs/BackgroundJobManager.cs#L51) I find that it's set to five seconds by default. However, I am not able to update the timer to update this. Even if I tried to disable it using the code below, it was unsuccessful and it is still running.

```
if (DebugHelper.IsDebug)
{
     Configuration.BackgroundJobs.IsJobExecutionEnabled = false;
}
```

To continue, is there a way to replace this background job to quartz only. I think in the case of adding Quartz integration, they both run concurrently.

Any help will be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to its [implementation](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/blob/dev/src/Abp/BackgroundJobs/BackgroundJobManager.cs#L51) the default value has been set to five seconds and this can be configured and overridden at the `PreInitialize` method of the `CoreModule`. All it needs is below:

```
public override void PreInitialize()
{
   ...

   BackgroundJobManager.JobPollPeriod = 20000; //20 seconds

   ...        
}
```